# Server 2012 RDS Session Host missing

Tags: windows-server-2012, rds

I've created a couple virtual servers in Azure, one a domain controller and the other is setup with the RDS role. I'm able to connect to the web app, but was only able to add "mstsc" along with the other apps. What I'd like to do is make available a desktop session utilizing UPD. I don't want to do virtual machine-based I believe, but session-based.

[image]

So from what I understand I need to create a new collection (or edit and existing one). When I try to create a new session, I go to collections, and add a new collection:

[image]

So now when I run the wizard, I am forced to select a session host, but none are listed. Do I have to spin up a new server for the Session Host, or why can't I used this own server and why isn't itself listed?

[image]

So please describe what I am doing wrong and if possible how I would continue on and create the remote desktop session that each individual could have "published" to their rd_web site?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the RDSession host server again by going back and deleting the default Collection. After doing so, I was able to create a new collection